# Why constant argument of function used as array size gives error?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

When I use the constant argument of a function as a array size in C++ it gives "Constant expression required" error:
[image]

So the compiler is not considering `m` as a constant object, this means I can change the value of `m` inside the function, but when I try to increment the value of `m` it gives "cannot modify a const object" error:
[image]

It is really ambiguous to me. Can anyone please explain what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: HOLY COW what program is this??? It looks like it's from before when I was born.. O_O

Comment: @Mehrdad It's the ancient Turbo C++.

Comment: Edited and retagged as C++ - C doesn't have default arguments.

Comment: Whoa, another person with a time machine! Voting to close as "too localized" since no one in the past 10 years has actually used Turbo C++. I wish all programming problems were as simple as "upgrade your compiler, solve all your problems".

Comment: Turbo Vision apps... F5 to maximize, F6 next window, Alt-X exit, wordstar keybindings (^K^B block begin etc). I **do** have a memory for key bindings. I loved me my Borland Turbo Pascal 5.5/6.0 too

Comment: @Cody: The problem has nothing to do with the age of the compiler, so your close vote is not appropriate here.

Comment: @Xeo: Then consider it a close vote because the code is shown in *image* form.

Comment: All of India appears to be fuelled by Turbo C++, so I wouldn't be so dismissive about it. 1 billion people can't be wrong, surely?

Comment: @Kerrek: Of course they can. Easily.

Comment: @Cody: What the...? If it's really itching you, edit it to remove those images and replace them with actual code / quotes of the errors, but you know, the current form is clear enough as-is. IMHO, anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` doesn't actually mean "this value is constant", but, "you cannot change this value."

With this, it should be clear why the latter code fails to compile but the former cannot. Even though you give it a default of `5`, that doesn't *guarantee* it's five, and so you don't have a constant, so you can't make an array. But the type is still `const`, so you can't change it.

That said, since C99 you can have variable-length arrays so this would actually be fine. (It is not okay in C++.) Your compiler just seems to be too old to support C99. (I highly recommend using the latest GCC.)

Comment: @Imran: in CodeBlocks, are you compiling with the `-ansi` or `-std=c++98` flags? And with warnings on?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create statically a variable-sized array. That is what `malloc()` is for. The compiler treats the constants as a variable even if they are delclared as const, because it knows nothing about them at compile time, so it can't produce compile-time code to create a static array.

Furthermore: if you declare m as `const int m=5`, why on Earth do you expect it to be able to increment? It's a constant, so you cannot possibly modify its value.

Nothing is ambigous here, you have just to think a bit about it.

Comment: I think C99 allows this by using something like `alloca` underneath?

Answer (score 2):

CodeBlocks is an editor/IDE, not a compiler. I assume it uses GCC for a compiler, which I think has an extension to use C99's variable-length arrays in C++.

This is not even in C++11 (and probably never will be in C++, since we have `std::vector`), so this is one of the very few cases where a 20 year old compiler actually got it right.

If I was you, though, I'd still dump TC++. It belongs into a museum.

Answer (score 0):

You need a *compile-time constant integral expression*.  Not just a `const`.